# WesBos JS30 Day 5 flex Panels - Modify code to close open panels except the one clicked on

Tags: javascript, flexbox

I am doing the awesome JS30 course by Wes Bos https://courses.wesbos.com/account/access/59ee449bd71f462ee56d1ccf/view/194130264 I'm doing day 5 Flex Panels and I want to modify his final result to close all open panels when I click on a new one.

I've created a function that does that called `removeOpen` but it also closes the one I've clicked on :(

```
const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');

function toggleOpen() {
  this.classList.toggle('open');
}

function removeOpen(e) {
  const openPanels = document.querySelectorAll('.open');
  console.log('removeOpen', this.classList);
  console.log('openPanels', openPanels);
  // this works too well, I need to stagger the command so it fires before toggleOpen
  openPanels.forEach(
    openPanel => openPanel.classList.remove('open')
  );
}

function toggleActive(e) {
  if(e.propertyName.includes('flex')) {
    this.classList.toggle('open-active');
  }
}

panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('click', toggleOpen));
// remove the line below to make it work as per the tutorial
panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('click', removeOpen));
panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('transitionend', toggleActive));
```

Here's a fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/wcuea0ur/ comment out `panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('click', removeOpen));` to make it work as per the tutorial.

Please can someone show me the light!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it I just needed to put removeOpen above toggleOpen.

So the new function order at the bottom is:

```
panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('click', removeOpen));
panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('click', toggleOpen));
panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('transitionend', toggleActive));
```

I'm surprised at how shockingly easy this turned out to be. The only thing it doesn't do now is close the current panel if clicked on but that's ok for my needs.

Here's an updated fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/tLf2woac/